# mongoose aggregate how to map multiple collections into one Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dictionary, mongoose, aggregate

I have four different collections. From which three are connected to one:

```
Collection_A = {
    _id: 1
    name: A
    includes: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            includes_id: 222,
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            includes_id: 333
        }
    ] 
}

Collection_B = {
    _id: 222,
    type: Computer,
    name: Computer,
    ref_id: 1
}

Collection_C = {
    _id: 333,
    type: Human,
    name: Human,
    ref_id: 1
}

Collection_D = {
    _id: 444,
    type: Animal,
    name: Animal,
    ref_id: 1
}
```

So collection A can include Collection B, C and D in the includes object. It includes minimum one of the collections.

So in the includes object in Collection A is the includes_id, which is the _id in Collection B, C and D.
The _id in Collection A is the ref_id in Collection B, C and D.

What my problem right now is, that aggregate takes only the last mapped collection.

My code right now is following:

```
     Collection_A.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "collectionb",
            localField: "includes.includes_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "colb",
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "collectionc",
            localField: "includes.includes_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "colc",
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            status: 1,
            type: 1,
            includes_list: {
              $map: {
                input: "$includes",
                as: "i",
                in: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                        {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$colb",
                            cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i.includes_id"],
                            },
                        },
                        },
                        0,
                    ],
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                        {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$colc",
                            cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i.includes_id"],
                            },
                        },
                        },
                        0,
                    ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ]);
```

I tried to make the $lookup as the same on every lookup, but so it only took the last looked up data, and the others where shown as null.
So I made $lookup as unique, and put two ins in map, but then also the last looked up data was shown, and the others where null.

When I do the mapping like that:

```
includes_list: {
    $map: {
    input: "$icludes",
    as: "i",
    in: {
        {
            Col_A : {
            $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$A",
                        cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i.includes"],
                        },
                    },
                },
                0,
            ],
            },
            Col_B : {
            $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$B",
                        cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i.includes"],
                        },
                    },
                },
                0,
            ],
            }
        }
    },
    },
}
```

It workes. But not with the right output, because I need includes_list within one array.

My desired output is like following:

```
{
    includes: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: Computer,
            includes_list: [
                {
                    _id: 222,
                    type: Computer,
                    name: Computer,
                    ref_id: 1
                },
                {
                    _id: 333,
                    type: Human,
                    name: Human,
                    ref_id: 1
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            name: Animal,
            includes_list: [
                {
                    _id: 333,
                    type: Human,
                    name: Human,
                    ref_id: 2
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation,
`$facet` help to categorize the incoming data

```
db.Collection_A.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$includes },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "joinB": [            
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "Collection_B", "localField": "includes.includes_id",
            "foreignField": "_id", "as": "includes.includes_list"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            includes: { $push: "$includes" }
          }
        }
      ],
      "joinC": [            
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "Collection_C", "localField": "includes.includes_id",
            "foreignField": "_id", "as": "includes.includes_list"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            includes: { $push: "$includes" }
          }
        }
      ],
      "joinD": [
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "Collection_D", "localField": "includes.includes_id",
            "foreignField": "_id", "as": "includes.includes_list"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            includes: { $push: "$includes" }
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      combined: {
        "$concatArrays": [ "$joinB", "$joinC", "$joinD" ]
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$combined" },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$combined" }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      includes: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$includes",
          cond: {
            $ne: [ "$$this.includes_list",[] ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NXZH2YbScak)**

Note: I feel this is kind of Anti pattern you follow. If you are in early stage of the project, better change the structure if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do it in a better way?

Comment: @soptro I don't know the domain model you are working. But you can use OOP conceps like inheritance. Eg : `Human extends Animal`, `Pets extends Animal`. So `Animal` has `name, age,type //HUMAN or PET`. `Human` has `language`. `Pets` has `some other fields`. Since both are extending form `Animal`, you can put both in one collection. When u retrieve in backend, you can use `instanceOf` to divide the objects using `type`. This is just for an example

Comment: No it didn't. I changed my system completely.