# aggregate multiple collections with same field mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, lookup, aggregation

I want to aggregate Collection A with Collection B and C.

Collection A's _id is saved in collection B and C as ret_id.

I tried following:

```
await col_A.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
          from: "col_B",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "ret_id",
          as: "task",
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "col_C",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "ret_id",
          as: "task",
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          name: { $first: "$name" },
          tasks: { $push: "$task" },
        },
      },
])
```

But like that it shows nothing. I also tried to put two groups, but than I wasn't able to have the output in only one array.

So my desired output is like that:

```
{
    _id: id,
    name: name,
    tasks: [
        {
            _id: id,
            task_name: task_name
            ret_id: ret_id,
            // from collection B
        },
        {
            _id: id,
            task_name: task_name
            ret_id: ret_id
            // from collection C
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoose aggregate how to map multiple collections into one Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546270/mongoose-aggregate-how-to-map-multiple-collections-into-one-array)

Comment: unfortunately not. In the array there I only get the result of only one $lookup.